# Why is recursion faster than a flat for loop for a summation function on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-construction

I'm working in a language that translates to JavaScript. In order to avoid some stack overflows, I'm applying tail call optimization by converting certain functions to for loops. What is surprising is that the conversion is **not** faster than the recursive version.

http://jsperf.com/sldjf-lajf-lkajf-lkfadsj-f/5

Recursive version:

```
(function recur(a0,s0){
    return a0==0 ? s0 : recur(a0-1, a0+s0)
})(10000,0)
```

After tail call optimization:

```
ret3 = void 0;
a1   = 10000;
s2   = 0;
(function(){
    while (!ret3) {
        a1 == 0 
            ? ret3     = s2
            : (a1_tmp$ = a1 - 1 ,
               s2_tmp$ = a1 + s2,
               a1      = a1_tmp$,
               s2      = s2_tmp$);
     }
})();
ret3;
```

After some cleanup using Google Closure Compiler:

```
ret3 = 0;
a1   = 1E4;
for(s2 = 0; ret3 == 0;)
    0 == a1 
        ? ret3     = s2 
        : (a1_tmp$ = a1 - 1 ,
           s2_tmp$ = a1 + s2,
           a1      = a1_tmp$,
           s2      = s2_tmp$);
c=ret3;
```

The recursive version is faster than the "optimized" ones! How can this be possible, if the recursive version has to handle thousands of context changes?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm working on that right now. Edit: done.

Comment: can i haz answarz naw

Comment: n = 10000, o=0; while(n) o += n--;

Comment: Which browser are you running these benchmarks on?  There's no telling what kinds of optimizations the Javascript engine is doing under the hood.

Comment: Chrome. Is there how to tell which optimizations you can expect?

Answer (score 5):

There's more to optimising than tail-call optimisation.

For instance, I notice you're using two temporary variables, when all you need is:

```
s2 += a1;
a1--;
```

This alone practically reduces the number of operations by a third, resulting in a performance increase of 50%

In the long run, it's important to optimise what operations are being performed before trying to optimise the operations themselves.

EDIT: Here's an updated [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/sldjf-lajf-lkajf-lkfadsj-f/2)

Comment: Interesting that even with your optimization, the recursive version is faster for me.

Comment: Well that's just weird XD Maybe it depends on the browser. I'm using IE10.

Comment: But I guess I need those temporary variables for the optimization, so they hold the initial values of the passed arguments before jumping back... otherwise cases like `a = a - 1; b = a + b` would go bad because "b" was supposed to use the old value of `a` on its sum? Except if I find a way to automate what you did manually but I have to think about that~

Comment: @Viclib You'll notice I switched the order, so it's `b = a + b; a = a - 1;` and now it works fine.

Comment: No, I mean, generally there is no way for my system to detect how to do that kind of manipulation, thus I need the extra variables (I'm not sure though). Anyway, interesting input. Also puzzled how it is still almost the same speed...

Comment: @Viclib Since all of them are effectively doing the same thing, in theory the browser should optimise them to the same operations and therefore be the same speed. However in practice there are too many potential side-effects for it to be safe to optimise, which is why you might see differences in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

as *Kolink* say what your piece of code do is simply adding `n` to the total, reduce `n` by 1, and loop  until `n` not reach `0`

so just do that :

```
n = 10000, o = 0; while(n) o += n--;
```

it's  [more faster](http://jsperf.com/sldjf-lajf-lkajf-lkfadsj-f/6) and lisible than the recursive version, and off course output the [same result](http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/DKLVB/)

Comment: Nice but generating simple code like that is not straightforward for a compiler, and the speed is still on par. I appreciate your answer but nobody is addressing the question directly: "why is the speed so similar, if the recursive version does a lot of heavy context switches"?

Comment: recursive code just do the minimal, the + on the total and the -- on n, your code does not, so the gain get by removing the recursion is counterbalanced by the use of your temp var. so, speed is not similar, Kolink solution is 5x faster than recursion => http://jsperf.com/sldjf-lajf-lkajf-lkfadsj-f/7

Answer (score 2):

There are not so much context changes inside the recursive version as you expect, since the named function `recur` is contained in the scope of `recur` itself/they share the same scope. The reason for that has to do with the way the JavaScript engines evaluate scope, and there are plenty of websites out there which explain this topic, so I will not do it here. At a second look you will notice that `recur` is also a so called "pure" function, which basically means it never has to leave it's own scope as long as the internal execution runs (simply put: until it returns a value). These two facts make it basically fast. I just want to mention here, the first example is the only tail call optimized one of all three – a tc optimization can only be done in recursive functions and this is the only recursive one.

However, a second look at the second example (no pun intended) reveals, that the "optimizer" made things worse for you, since it introduced scopes into the former pure function by splitting the operation into

- variables instead of arguments
- a `while` loop
- a IIFE (immediatly invoked function expression) that separates the introduced inner and outer variables

Which leads to poorer performance since now the engine has to handle 10000 context changes.

To tell you the truth I do not know why the third example is poorer in performance than the recursive one, so maybe it has to do with:

- the browser you use (ever tried another one and compared the results?)
- the number of variables
- stack frames created by for-loops (never heard of though), which
  would have to do with the first example: the JS engines interpret a
  pure recursive function until it finds a return statement. If the last thing following the statement is a function call, then evaluate any expressions (if any) and variables to pass as arguments, call the function and throw away the frame
- something, only the browser-vendors can truly tell you :)